# Proving correctness of Polynomial reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions

Given a problem A is NP-Hard and  A ≤ B, is there a way to prove that B is also NP-Hard?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking.  The title doesn't match the body of your question.  What are your thoughts?  What reading have you done, and what attempts have you made?  It's hard to understand what your level of understanding is.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of NP-Hard states: "A problem $L$ is NP-Hard, if for every problem $L'\in NP$, there exists a polynomial reduction from $L'$ to $L$, namely - $L'\le_p L$".

Now, since $A$ is NP-Hard, that would mean that for any $L'\in NP$, we have $L'\le_p A$. Since the relation $\le_p$ is transitive (prove it!), we also have $L'\le_p B$. Hence, by definition $B$ is also NP-Hard.